# How to correctly set up laravel project inside another laravel project?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5.3

For example I have set laravel project in domain:

example.com

But I want to set another Laravel project in:

example.com/shared

How to correctly set up htaccess? Or I have to configure other files as well?

Comment: You want to move files to shared folder but do not want to use shared in url?

Comment: No, I want to use also 'shared' folder for other project. For now what happens is, if I type example.com/shared, it gives error from project in example.com, that the page doesn't exist.